# average of every number in list

Tags: python

Fisherman Alex needs to enter amount of fish he catched every day for 10 days.

Program needs to return average for every day and number of day he catched more fish than average

```
list = []
i = 1
while i < 11:
    fish = int(input("Enter amount of catched fish: "))
    list.append(fish)
    i+=1

total = sum(list)
```

This is what i did so far..

Comment: Put total = sum(list) before i+=1 in your loop. By dividing it to i you will have average for every number.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "average of every number instead of average of whole list"?

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is a rolling average? The rolling average will be a list where the 1st element is the average for the 1st day, the 2nd element is the average for the 1st and 2nd days, the 3rd element is the average for the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd days, etc. The n'th element in your rolling average is the average over the first n days.

Comment: Do yourself a favor - while figuring out the math, use a list of 10 ints.  Once done, put the inputs back in.  Entering stuff, esp this, is tedious, breaks your flow and makes it hard to redo edge cases automatically.

Answer (score 4):

The average is typically calculated as the sum divided by the number of elements.
So let's mimic that in python.

```
list = []
above_average_days = 0
for i in range(0,10):
    fish_today = int(input("Enter amount of fish caught : "))
    list.append(fish_today)

    # calculate average
    fish_average = sum(list) / len(list)

    # do something when fish_today > average
    if fish_today > fish_average:
        print('You caught more fish than average today. Congratulations!')
        above_average_days += 1

# Finally print the number of days where the fishes performed above average
print('You caught more than average on {} days.'.format(above_average_days))
```

Comment: To answer the second part of the question, you might add a list comprehension to return the number of list elements that are above average, i.e. `days_over = len([x for x in total if x > average])`

Comment: Joris thanks this is what i was looking for but i need program to display which numbers from list are higher than average not how many of them...

Comment: If you feel this response answers your question, please mark it as the accepted answer so that other people might be helped as well. As for displaying the numbers that are higher, I'm sure you can work that out given the solution I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of the file:

```
average_number = total / len(list)
```

`average_number` will be your averaged value.